# Get Dreamweaver to highlight .mako files as .html

Tags: dreamweaver, mako, paster

Ideally, I would like to be able to treat a site built using Mako templates in Dreamweaver, as I'm merely working on the design aspect. I imagine the work will go much faster if I could edit .mako files in Dreamweaver and have it render the file like it would with HTML.

I've set up AMP servers to develop in Dreamweaver, and I'm hoping I can use a Paster webserver in the same way. More-over, though, just for ease, I'd like to have an extension or a setting in Dreamweaver that would allow me to treat it like a normal HTML-based site - that's all .mako is, basically, is HTML (like PHP) with a .mako extension on it.

Currently, my Extensions.txt file contains this:
`HTM,HTML,SHTM,SHTML,HTA,HTC,XHTML,STM,SSI,JS,JSON,AS,ASC,ASR,XML,XSL,XSD,DTD,XSLT,RSS,RDF,LBI,DWT,ASP,ASA,ASPX,ASCX,ASMX,CONFIG,CS,CSS,CFM,CFML,CFC,TLD,TXT,PHP,PHP3,PHP4,PHP5,PHP-DIST,PHTML,JSP,WML,TPL,LASSO,JSF,VB,VBS,VTM,VTML,INC,SQL,JAVA,EDML,MASTER,INFO,INSTALL,THEME,CONFIG,MODULE,PROFILE,ENGINE,SVG,MAKO:All Documents
HTM,HTML,HTA,HTC,XHTML,MAKO:HTML Documents
SHTM,SHTML,STM,SSI,INC:Server-Side Includes
JS,JSON:JavaScript Documents
XML,DTD,XSD,XSL,XSLT,RSS,RDF:XML Files
LBI:Library Files
DWT:Template Files
CSS:Style Sheets
ASP,ASA:Active Server Pages
ASPX,ASCX,ASMX,CS,VB,CONFIG,MASTER:Active Server Plus Pages
CFM,CFML,CFC:ColdFusion Templates
AS:ActionScript Files
ASC:ActionScript Communication Files
ASR:ActionScript Remote Files
TXT:Text Files
PHP,PHP3,PHP4,PHP5,TPL,PHP-DIST,PHTML:PHP Files
LASSO:Lasso Files
JSP,JST:Java Server Pages
JSF:Fireworks Script
TLD:Tag Library Descriptor Files
JAVA:Java Files
SQL:SQL Files
ASX:Windows Media Advanced Stream Redirector
WML:WML Files
EDML:EDML Files
VBS:VBScript Files
VTM,VTML:VTML Files
SVG:Scalable Vector Graphics Files`

Note that the MAKO reference is on the first line, as :All Documents, and again in the :HTML Documents

Here's my MMDocumentTypes.xml document, which includes near the last entry.

 `<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <documenttypes xmlns:MMString="http://www.macromedia.com/schemes/data/string/">
    <documenttype id="HTML" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,stm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,mako" macfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,mako,ssi" file="Default.html" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_0" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_1" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype> 
    <documenttype id="ASP-JS" servermodel="ASP JavaScript" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="asp" macfileextension="asp" file="Default_js.asp" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_4" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_5" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype> 
    <documenttype id="ASP-VB" servermodel="ASP VBScript" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="asp" macfileextension="asp" file="Default_vb.asp" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_2" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_3" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="ColdFusion" servermodel="ColdFusion" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="cfm,cfml" macfileextension="cfm,cfml" file="Default.cfm" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_6" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_7" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="CFC" servermodel="ColdFusion" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="cfc" macfileextension="cfc" file="Default.cfc" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_56" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_57" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>none</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="JSP" servermodel="JSP" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="jsp,jst" macfileextension="jsp,jst" file="Default.jsp" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_8" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_9" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="ASP.NET_VB" servermodel="ASP.NET VB" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="aspx,ascx,asmx" macfileextension="aspx,ascx" file="Default_vb.aspx" writebyteordermark="true" newdocumentname="WebForm" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_12" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_13" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="ASP.NET_CSharp" servermodel="ASP.NET C#" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="aspx,ascx,asmx" macfileextension="aspx,ascx" file="Default_cs.aspx" writebyteordermark="true" newdocumentname="WebForm" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_10" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_11" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="PHP_MySQL" servermodel="PHP MySQL" internaltype="Dynamic" winfileextension="php,php3,php4,php5,phtml" macfileextension="php,php3,php4,php5,phtml" file="Default.php" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_14" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_15" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="JavaScript" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="js,json" macfileextension="js,json" file="Default.js" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/javascript">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_16" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_17" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="VBScript" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="vbs" macfileextension="vbs" file="Default.vbs" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/vbscript">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_18" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_19" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="Csharp" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="cs" macfileextension="cs" file="Default.cs" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/cs">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_20" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_21" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="VB" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="vb" macfileextension="vb" file="Default.vb" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/vb">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_22" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_23" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="Java" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="java" macfileextension="java" file="Default.java" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/java">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_24" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_25" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate" internaltype="DWTemplate" winfileextension="dwt" macfileextension="dwt" file="Default.dwt" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_26" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_27" /> 
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="EDML" internaltype="XML" winfileextension="edml,edm" macfileextension="edml,edm" file="Default.edml" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xml" >
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_28" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_29" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>none</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="CSS" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="css" macfileextension="css" file="Default.css" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/css" >
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_30" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_31" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="XML" internaltype="XML" winfileextension="xml,xsd,rss,rdf,dtd,vtm,vtml,csn,config,mxi" macfileextension="xml,xsd,rss,rdf,dtd,vtm,vtml,csn,config,mxi" file="Default.xml" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xml" >
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_32" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_33" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>xml</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
  <documenttype id="Actionscript" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="as" macfileextension="as" file="Default.as" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/as" >
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_34" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_35" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="Text" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="txt" macfileextension="txt" file="Default.txt" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/plain" >
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_36" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_37" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="WML" internaltype="XML" winfileextension="wml" macfileextension="wml" file="Default.wml" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xml">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_38" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_39" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>wml</dtdcontext>
        <dtdcontext>required</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="TLD" internaltype="XML" winfileextension="tld" macfileextension="tld" file="Default.tld" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xml">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_58" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_59" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>jsp_tag_library</dtdcontext>
        <dtdcontext>required</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="LibraryItem" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="lbi" macfileextension="lbi" file="Default.lbi" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_40" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_41" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>none</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_ASPVB" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="ASP-VB" winfileextension="dwt.asp" macfileextension="dwt.asp" file="Default_vb.dwt.asp" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_42" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_43" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_ASPJS" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="ASP-JS" winfileextension="dwt.asp" macfileextension="dwt.asp" file="Default_js.dwt.asp" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_44" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_45" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_CF" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="ColdFusion" winfileextension="dwt.cfm" macfileextension="dwt.cfm" file="Default.dwt.cfm" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_46" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_47" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_JSP" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="JSP" winfileextension="dwt.jsp" macfileextension="dwt.jsp" file="Default.dwt.jsp" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_48" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_49" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_AXCS" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="ASP.NET_CSharp" winfileextension="dwt.aspx" macfileextension="dwt.aspx" file="Default_cs.dwt.aspx" writebyteordermark="true" newdocumentname="WebForm" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_50" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_51" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_AXVB" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="ASP.NET_VB" winfileextension="dwt.aspx" macfileextension="dwt.aspx" file="Default_vb.dwt.aspx" writebyteordermark="true" newdocumentname="WebForm" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_52" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_53" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="DWTemplate_PHP" internaltype="DWTemplate" dynamicid="PHP_MySQL" winfileextension="dwt.php" macfileextension="dwt.php" file="Default.dwt.php" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_54" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_55" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="ASComm" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="asc" macfileextension="asc" file="Default.asc" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/asc">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_60" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_61" /> 
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="ASRemote" internaltype="Text" winfileextension="asr" macfileextension="asr" file="Default.asr" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/asr">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_62" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_63" />
        </description>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="XSLT" servermodel="XSLT" internaltype="XSLT" dynamicid="XSLT" winfileextension="xsl,xslt" macfileextension="xsl,xslt" file="Default.xsl" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xsl">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_66" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_67" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>xslt</dtdcontext>
        <dtdcontext>required</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="XSLT-fragment" servermodel="XSLT" internaltype="XSLT" dynamicid="XSLT" winfileextension="xsl,xslt" macfileextension="xsl,xslt" file="Default-fragment.xsl" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xsl">
        <TITLE>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_68" />
        </TITLE>
        <description>
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_69" />
        </description>
        <dtdcontext>none</dtdcontext>
        <dtdcontext>required</dtdcontext>
    </documenttype>
    <documenttype id="MAKO" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="mako" macfileextension="mako" file="Default.mako" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html"> 
        <TITLE> 
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_74" /> 
        </TITLE> 
        <description> 
            <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_75" /> 
        </description> 
        <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext> 
    </documenttype> 
  <documenttype id="SVG" internaltype="XML" winfileextension="svg" macfileextension="svg" file="Default.svg" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/xml" >
    <TITLE>
      <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_72" />
    </TITLE>
    <description>
      <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_73" />
    </description>
    <dtdcontext>svg</dtdcontext>
    <dtdcontext>required</dtdcontext>
  </documenttype>

</documenttypes>`

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nearly a month... There must be an answer out there. Are there no Mako users on teams, with a designer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .mako extension to the Extensions.txt file and also assign it a file type in the MMDocumentTypes.xml file.  There is a [TechNote](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/change-add-recognized-file-extensions.html) that covers both of these instructions and also provides the file locations.

Comment: Adding mako to the HTML types does not work. That's `HTM,HTML,HTA,HTC,XHTML,MAKO:HTML Documents` in Extensions.txt and `<documenttype id="HTML" internaltype="HTML" winfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,stm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,mako" macfileextension="html,htm,shtml,shtm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,mako,ssi" file="Default.html" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/html">
  <TITLE>
   <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_0" />
  </TITLE>
  <description>
   <MMString:loadString id="mmdocumenttypes_1" />
  </description>
  <dtdcontext>html</dtdcontext>
 </documenttype> ` for the MMDocumentTypes.xml entry.

Comment: My expectation is that I would be able to use the Code, Split, or Design view, with inherited styles, just like a PHP / MySQL site

Answer (score 0):

As JCL1178 noted, instead of making a new XML entry in MMDocumentTypes.xml, try adding MAKO to the first HTML entry under winfileextension and macfileextension. That worked for me.

Did you make sure to remove it from the "open in code view" extension in Preferences?

> Open in Code View
>
> The Open in Code View preference identifies file extensions that do
>   not allow Design view. After following the instructions in this
>   TechNote, be sure to remove the file extension (if it is listed) from
>   the Open In Code View preference to allow file editing in Design view.
>   To set this preference, choose Edit > Preferences (Windows) or
>   Dreamweaver > Preferences (Mac OS), and locate the File Types /
>   Editors category.

Comment: I tried this just now, and no joy. I would just as soon have Dreamweaver treat .mako templates like .html.  Here is my Open In Code View list: `.js .asa .css .inc .txt .as .asc .asr .htaccess .htpasswd`

Comment: Here is my macfileextensions value: `html,htm,shtml,shtm,tpl,lasso,xhtml,mako,ssi`

Comment: did you delete the Mako document type XML entry that you made from  MMDocumentTypes.xml also?

I did the same thing as you with ftl files, added to Extensions.txt (all and html entries) then added to html document type. Restarted DW and works in design and code.

What version of DW are you using (works on DW6)? Maybe double-check you're editing the right file locations also.